# Check share point if file exists in a shared document folder with power automate

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, automation, power-automate

I am trying to get the attachments of some emails and check if that attachment already exists in SharePoint. However, since the flow may have already run over some attachments that have already been received, they may or may not already be in SharePoint, so I first have to check SharePoint if the attachment exists and if they don't, create the file using the email attachment content.

So what I have so far is replicating a process that was described [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Check-if-file-exists-in-Sharepoint-folder/td-p/327730)

The problem that quickly arises is that under "Get file content using path" action, the File Path input box(circled below) won't let me append a file path that isn't currently already in a document folder.

[image: Current power automate flow]

Not sure if this is still a valid way to accomplish it or if there's another way. I have checked all over the place and still haven't been able to find a solution. If there's anybody that can help it would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

To tackle this what you can do is to create a variable using `Initialize variable` action and compose the `path` e.g. *'/DocumentLibrary/file.ext'* that you want to check if exists. then you can  refer to that variable in your `folder path` box for `Get file content using path` action. Please see the screenshot:
[image]

Next you can `configure run after`for file creation action and create file if `Get file content using path` action has ***failed***, otherwise do other stuff that is required. I have tested this for sending different emails based upon file found or not found and it works well.
Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Hey Muhammad! So what you are saying works but only when you know the name of the file beforehand. I am trying to dynamically go through all emails get the name of the email attachments and if they contain certain text and have the right extension, check if SharePoint has them and if not move them into Sharepoint. The initialize variable only works if it is placed at the top-level although when I am checking the emails it gets nested under the attachment conditions. The help is greatly appreciated but as you can tell it has been frustrating!

Comment: @AmandoGarza.. yeah you got to initialize the variables at the top and you can still go with that. After initializing variable you can use `Set Variable` action. you can place it anywhere depending upon where you get the file name, set path and use according to your logic.